# How to split a number and add and then split until a 1 digit number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically I have my program set up so that it takes in names and then splits them until it gets to a number between 1 and 9 so if the number is 35 it would split to add 5 and 3 which gives 8. My problem with my program is that if I ask to enter only 1 name it gives an error but 2 and up names work? Also it has to work if the number goes up to 325 as it would need to be 3+2+5 then and then after that it would be 10 then that would split again to give 1+0 which is then 1. At the end I want to also be able to have a meaning = " " and the totalValue from 1 to 9 would have a meaning like this value means your strong or a thinker or a good speaker or whatever. The main problem is with the list of names is there a way I can bypass the restriction of only one number in the num_names so that I can have 1 all the way up to an infinite number? What do I do?
 I believe this code may be of help but Im not sure.
list_names = list(names)

```
def name_value(name):
    return sum((ord(chr) - 65) % 9 + 1 for chr in name)

totalValue = 0
for list_name in names:
    totalValue += name_value(list_name)
```

I don't know where to put this though

```
import sys


print("Please enter each name when asked without any spaces.") #The program will post this
print("Please enter each of your names individually also.")    #Program will again post this




names = [] #This is the value of names which will be changed depending on the input
currentnum = 0 #Currentnum value is 0

while True:
    try:
    num_names = int(input("Enter number of names: "))
    break
except ValueError:
        print("That's not a number!")



for i in range(num_names):
name = input("Enter name " + str(i) + " :")
name = name.upper()
while True:
    if name.isalpha():
        break
    else:
           name = input("Enter name number " + str(i) + " again:")
names.append(name)


num1 = ["A", "J", "S"]
num2 = ["B", "K", "T"]
num3 = ["C", "L", "U"]
num4 = ["D", "M", "V"]    #This is a dictionary giving all the upper case letters a value of num1, num2 etc
num5 = ["E", "N", "W"]
num6 = ["F", "O", "X"]
num7 = ["G", "P", "Y"]
num8 = ["H", "Q", "Z"]
num9 = ["I", "R"]

totalValue = 0

list_names = list(names)

first_name = list_names[0]
second_name = list_names[1]
#third_name = list_names[2]

print(first_name)
print(second_name)
#print(third_name)
print(list_names)




for chr in first_name:      #if, elif and else code
        if (chr in num1):
                totalValue += 1
        elif (chr in num2):
                totalValue += 2
        elif (chr in num3):
                totalValue += 3
        elif (chr in num4): 
                totalValue += 4       #This gives TotalValue(the number answer) depending on the letter
        elif (chr in num5): 
                totalValue += 5
        elif (chr in num6): 
                totalValue += 6
        elif (chr in num7):
                totalValue += 7
        elif (chr in num8):
                totalValue += 8
        elif (chr in num9):
                totalValue += 9
    else:
            print("program failure")


for chr in second_name:      #if, elif and else code
    if (chr in num1):
            totalValue += 1
    elif (chr in num2):
            totalValue += 2
    elif (chr in num3):
            totalValue += 3
    elif (chr in num4): 
            totalValue += 4       #This gives TotalValue(the number answer) depending on the letter
    elif (chr in num5): 
            totalValue += 5
    elif (chr in num6): 
            totalValue += 6
    elif (chr in num7):
            totalValue += 7
    elif (chr in num8):
            totalValue += 8
    elif (chr in num9):
            totalValue += 9
    else:
            print("You have entered invalid inputs for names. Program will Now end.")




values = []
totalCount = 0
for x in values:                           #This will activate or iterate the loop for the value
    totalCount = totalCount + x     #This will add all the values together and to give a totalcount


while len(str(totalValue)) != 1:        #The code will split the 2 digit number until the addition equals to 1 digit 
        num = 0 
        for x in str(totalValue):       #This is the value x in the string     totalcount
            num = num + int(x)       #This means that the number being output will have the int of the value x
            totalValue = str(num)    #The totalCount must equal to the string of num

#[int(d) for d in str(totalValue)]    

print(totalValue)
```

Comment: `values = []` and then you attempt to sum all the data contained in `values`. This looks really suspicious.

Comment: wow, not sure what is harder to read if your question or the code!! Can you just say what you need in a few simple sentences, perhaps 2 or 3 examples?

Comment: Basically I want it to ask how many names you have then after that it will ask you for a name the amount of times of the number u entered for amount of names and then after that split them and add together until the final totalValue is 1-9. I found this it may help but where will it go in my code. list_names = list_names = list(names) def name_value(name): return sum((ord(chr)-65) % 9 + 1 for chr in name) totalValue = 0 for list_name in names: totalValue+= name_value(list_name)

Comment: start with simpler problems, for example FizzBuzz.

Comment: Let's say I give two names: "John" and "smith" what is the expected result?

Comment: @Algina It would then equal (1+6+8+5) + (1+4+9+2+8) this would add together to give 20 + 24 which is 44 this would then split and add to give 4+4 which gives 8 so final value is 8

Comment: Ok, understand now, look at my answer, looks fancy I guess :)

Comment: I will suggest you to edit your question and make it a bit easier to read. and don't forget to vote up if you like my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got not what you want. 
Take a look:

```
import sys

def sumString2Digit(the_char):
    d = ord(the_char.upper()) - 65 + 1
    r = 0
    while d:
        r, d = r + d % 10, d // 10
        if d == 0 and r >= 10 :
            d = r
            r = 0
    return r

#all_names = "John Smith" #Expected output: 44
all_names = raw_input("Enter ALL names separated by spaces: ")
names  = all_names.split(' ')

res = []
for name in names:
    res.append(sum(map(lambda x: sumString2Digit(x), name)))
print ("the code for {} is {}".format(all_names, sum(res)))
```

**Example:**

```
$python <scriptName>
$Enter ALL names separated by spaces: John Smith
$the code for John Smith is 44
```